# query posts by my facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a facebook app that posts messages on user's wall.  Is there a way for me to query all the posts created by all users using my app (for a certain time period)?

I don't want to query just the posts made by my app for a specific user but all the wall posts made by my application.

Thanks.

Comment: This may not help you solve this question, but another approach you can take is to capture and save the postid that you get back when posts are created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stream table. It has an app_id field.
Down side is it is limited to the last 30 days or last 50 posts.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/